# R query sql from data.table values list

Tags: sql, r

given the following data:

```
library(data.table)
Name <- c('Plato','Hegel','Nietzsche')                      
Amount <- c(10,20,30)                     
ID <- c('x01','x02','y02') 
dt <- data.table(Name, Amount, ID) 
philos <- dt[["Name"]] 
philos
```

how can I create philos in a way that is possible to run:

```
query <- glue_sql("select * from philosophers where names in ({philos*})", .con = con)
```

I would need to get something like that is understood in sql like:

```
names in ('Plato','Hegel','Nietzsche')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `philos` as you currently have constructed it; just pass it as a named argument to `glue_sql()`:

```
glue::glue_sql(
  "select * FROM philosophers where names in ({philos*})",
  philos = philos,
  .con=con
)

<SQL> select * FROM philosophers where names in ('Plato', 'Hegel', 'Nietzsche')
```